# ESPNOW failed after I use WiFi.begin(ssid,password)

Tags: esp32, esp-now

I am doing a project of RFID access control system. I use 2 esp32. The first one connect to Google Sheet App Stripe, determine whether the uid detected is correct. Then it get the returned result.Then, it should send the result to the second esp32 by using ESP-NOW.
The first step works well which I can get back the returned result, but it cannot send to the second esp32(Delivery Fail). I found that the failure reason of ESP-NOW is because of the code `WiFi.begin(ssid,password)`(ESP-NOW works after I delete this code).
I want to know is that possible to use wifi and esp-now at the same time?
The logic of my project:
[image]

Comment: I have read somewhere that both ESP-NOW and Wifi need to be on the same channel for them to work both at the same time.

Comment: We can't help you without your code. Please update your post with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @OliverMason Yeap, I also see this on ESPRESSIF website. It mentions that `the channel of ESP-NOW must be the same as that of the connected AP`. But I don't know how to check the channel of the connected AP and how to change the channel of ESP-NOW, do you have any idea?